# Check or uncheck all enabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to toggle all enabled checkboxes when click on '#leg-chkAll', but
I am missing something!

If possible put some comment explaining the javascript code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#leg-chkAll).on('click', function () {
  $('div#legend').find('div :checkbox:enabled')     
   .prop('checked', this.checked)
   .find('tbody :checkbox').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);

 });
});
```

```html
<div id="leg-chkAll">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="leg-des">All</span>
</div>
<div id="legend">
    <div id="leg-evt1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="leg-chk" checked>
        <span class="leg-cod ev-event1">E1</span>
        <span class="leg-des">Event1</span>
        <span class="leg-day">1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="leg-evt2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="leg-chk" checked>
        <span class="leg-cod ev-event2">E2</span>
        <span class="leg-des">Event2</span>
        <span class="leg-day">10</span>
    </div>
    <div id="leg-evt3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="leg-chk" checked>
        <span class="leg-cod ev-event3">E3</span>
        <span class="leg-des">Event3</span>
        <span class="leg-day">3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="leg-evt4">
        <input type="checkbox" class="leg-chk" disabled>
        <span class="leg-cod ev-event4">E4</span>
        <span class="leg-des">Event4</span>
        <span class="leg-day">0</span>
    </div>
    <div id="leg-evt5">
        <input type="checkbox" class="leg-chk" checked>
        <span class="leg-cod ev-event5">E5</span>
        <span class="leg-des">Event5</span>
        <span class="leg-day">6</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. It looks like you're simply missing the closing single quote here: `$('#leg-chkAll)`.
2. `#leg-chkAll` is the `id` of the first div, but you want to listen for the click on the first checkbox, not the containing div.

It'll work if you put that `id` on the checkbox element. Change the first chunk of HTML to:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="leg-chkAll" checked>
  <span class="leg-des">All</span>
</div>
```

And then modify your jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#leg-chkAll').on('click', function () {
    $('#legend').find(':checkbox:enabled').prop('checked', this.checked)
  });
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9w944z9/